# Strange Pojo generated for a Json object by jsonschema2pojo.org

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is the first time I am posting a question here :

I have a json structure of this kind :

```
    "{  \"element\": ["
        + "    {"
        + "      \"name\": \"name1\",\n"
        + "      \"value\": \"Married\"\n"
        + "    },"
        + "    {"
        + "      \"name\": \"name2\",\n"
        + "      \"value\": 0\n"
        + "    },"
        + "    {"
        + "      \"name\": \"name3\",\n"
        + "      \"value\": 0\n"
        + "    }"
        + "  ] }"
```

The POJO that is generated looks like this :

```
public class Element {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If there were just one name value property as the POJO indicates, I understand that it is straightforward to just set those properties, saying something like element.setName(), element.setValue.

But how do I set values in this POJO for it to result in a Json structure as my example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Pojo to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593409/convert-pojo-to-json)

Comment: Also take a look at GSON. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: You're right that the POJO doesn't seem to fit your Json. Your Json snippet is not a correct json object - are you just missing opening and closing brackets? What library did you use to generate the POJO?

Comment: I use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which internally seems to use Jackson.Yes, I am just missing the braces. I use a valid one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you just forgot about the second class it generates. For your json:

```
{
    "element": [ 
      { "name": "name1",
        "value": "Married"
      }, 
      { "name": "name2",
        "value": 0
      },
      { "name": "name3",
        "value": 0
      }  ]
}
```

The tool, http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, generates the following code (when set to Jackson 2.x annotations and source type JSON):

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Elemant.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("com.googlecode.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"name",
"value"
})
public class Elemant {

@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("value")
private Integer value;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
return name;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty("value")
public Integer getValue() {
return value;
}

@JsonProperty("value")
public void setValue(Integer value) {
this.value = value;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperties(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("com.googlecode.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"element"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("element")
private List<Elemant> element = new ArrayList<Elemant>();
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("element")
public List<Elemant> getElement() {
return element;
}

@JsonProperty("element")
public void setElement(List<Elemant> element) {
this.element = element;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperties(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

So it is in fact the class `Example` that is the POJO you want, it contains a list of the `Element` POJOs. `Element` is the POJO generated for type of object in the array. Note that the class is called `Example` because that's the default name for the top-level object set by jsonschema2pojo.org. You can change it in the input field on the right side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is I use the same in my code, but with that structure the generated xml (I use that to convert to json later) looks like this :                                 <element>
        <name>name1</name>
        <value>value1</value>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>name2</name>
        <value>value2</value>
    </element>   whereas I want it to be like     <element>
        <name>name1</name>
        <value>value1</value>
        <name>name2</name>
        <value>value2</value>
    </element>

Comment: Please excuse the poor formatting. Looks like pressing the return key ends up submitting the comment, when posting a comment.

Comment: well, that's an entirely different question :) and it's still not clear to me - you take the above POJOs and use them to generate the XML? How? Please update your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Thank you for following up...I was able to get it to work. The POJO that was generated just had name, value properties. I corrected it, to include a map of name, value properties(with getter/setters for that map) and a list property to hold the maps. Now when I create some maps and assign it to the list, I just say something like, element.setList(list_of_maps of name-value pairs), and it generatesthe xsd/json in the format I want.