# Create JSONObject from POJO

Tags: java, json

I created a simple POJO:

```
public class LoginPojo {
    private String login_request = null;
    private String email = null;
    private String password = null;

    // getters, setters
}
```

After some searching I found this: [`JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject( loginPojo );`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593409/convert-pojo-to-json)

But with this I got the error:

```
The constructor JSONObject(LoginPojo) is undefined
```

I found another solution:

```
JSONObject loginJson = new JSONObject();
loginJson.append(loginPojo);
```

But this method does not exist.

So how can I convert my POJO into a JSON?

Comment: did you check out jsonSerializer/de-serializer?

Comment: Try using `GSON` library and `gson.toJsonTree(yourObject).getAsJsonObject()`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Simply use the java [**Gson** API](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);// obj is your object
```

And then you can create a `JSONObject` from this json `String`, like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Take a look at [**Gson user guide**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) and this [**SIMPLE GSON EXAMPLE**](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/) for more information.

Comment: The author asked to transform POJO to type JSONObject, not to type (json) String with gson. In a narrow sense, this is not answering the question.

Comment: @Samuel It is far so simple to get it.

You just need to pass this string to a new `JSONObject` constructor like this: `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);` or using **JSONParser** `.parse()` method.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I am not advocating to down vote your answer.

Comment: @Samuel No it's fine, I was just clarifying, any way your question was evident too.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to get a (gson) JsonObject from POJO:

```
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(userNested);
JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
```

After that you can take `object.entrySet()` and look up all the tree.

It is the only absolutely free way in GSON to set dynamically what fields you want to see.

Comment: This solution worked for me at  `gson-2.2.4` version.

Answer (score 5):

`Jackson` provides JSON parser/JSON generator as foundational building block; and adds a powerful Databinder (JSON<->POJO) and Tree Model as optional add-on blocks. This means that you can read and write JSON either as stream of tokens (Streaming API), as Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs, databind) or as Trees (Tree Model). [for more reference](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

You have to add `jackson-core-asl-x.x.x.jar`, `jackson-mapper-asl-x.x.x.jar` libraries to configure `Jackson` in your project.

Modified Code :

```
LoginPojo loginPojo = new LoginPojo();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    // Setting values to POJO
    loginPojo.setEmail("a@a.com");
    loginPojo.setLogin_request("abc");
    loginPojo.setPassword("abc");

    // Convert user object to json string
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(loginPojo);

    // Display to console
    System.out.println(jsonString);

} catch (JsonGenerationException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Output : 
{"login_request":"abc","email":"a@a.com","password":"abc"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
JSONObject input = new JSONObject(pojo);
```

This worked with latest version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) with Gson overriding toString function. It automatically includes builders, getters and setters in order to ease the data assignment like this:

```
User user = User.builder().username("test").password("test").build();
```

Find below the example class:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    /* User name. */
    private String username;
    /* Password. */
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this, User.class);
    }

    public static User fromJSON(String json) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, User.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use the below solution:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(loginPojo);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use jackson in my project, but I think that u need a empty constructor.

```
public LoginPojo(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
   <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.13</version>
 </dependency>
```

To create a JSON object:

```
@Test
public void whenGenerateJson_thanGenerationCorrect() throws ParseException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("AGE", 10);
        jsonObject.put("FULL NAME", "Doe " + i);
        jsonObject.put("DATE OF BIRTH", "2016/12/12 12:12:12");
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
    }
    String jsonOutput = jsonArray.toJSONString();
}
```

Add the annotations to your POJO class like so:

```
@JSONField(name = "DATE OF BIRTH")
private String dateOfBirth;
etc...
```

Then you can simply use:

```
@Test
public void whenJson_thanConvertToObjectCorrect() {
    Person person = new Person(20, "John", "Doe", new Date());
    String jsonObject = JSON.toJSONString(person);
    Person newPerson = JSON.parseObject(jsonObject, Person.class);

    assertEquals(newPerson.getAge(), 0); // if we set serialize to false
    assertEquals(newPerson.getFullName(), listOfPersons.get(0).getFullName());
}
```

You can find a more complete tutorial on the following site:
https://www.baeldung.com/fastjson

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with jackson and these versions of JSONObject which only accepts Map as constructor parameter:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(objectMapper.convertValue(pojo, Map.class));
```