# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file with some RestControllers.

In 1 of the controller this is the body I send:

```
{
    "depositHotel": "xxx",
    "destinationHotel": "aaa",
    "depositHotelAmount": "0.2",
    "destinationHotelAmount": "4",
    "destinationAddress": [{
        "address": "asdf",
        "tag": ""
    }],
    "refundAddress": [{
        "address": "pio",
        "tag": ""
    }]
}
```

so I create this class to send it as a RequestBody:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"address",
"tag"
})
public class Address {



    public Address() {
        super();
    }

    public Address(String address) {
        super();
        this.address = address;
    }

    @JsonProperty("address")
    private String address;
    @JsonProperty("tag")
    private Object tag;


    @JsonProperty("address")
    public String getAddress() {
    return address;
    }

    @JsonProperty("address")
    public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
    }

    @JsonProperty("tag")
    public Object getTag() {
    return tag;
    }

    @JsonProperty("tag")
    public void setTag(Object tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

and

public class HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody {

```
    public static class Builder {

        private String depositHotel;
        private String destinationHotel;
        private Float depositHotelAmount;
        private Float destinationHotelAmount;
        private Address destinationAddress;
        private Address refundAddress;


        public Builder(String depositHotel, String destinationHotel) {
            this.depositHotel = depositHotel;
            this.destinationHotel = destinationHotel;
        }

        public Builder withDepositHotelAmount (Float depositHotelAmount) {
            this.depositHotelAmount = depositHotelAmount;
            return this;  
        }

        public Builder withDestinationHotelAmount (Float destinationHotelAmount) {
            this.destinationHotelAmount = destinationHotelAmount;
            return this;  
        }

        public Builder toDestinationAddress (Address destinationAddress) {
            this.destinationAddress = destinationAddress;
            return this;  
        }

        public Builder toRefundAddress (Address refundAddress) {
            this.refundAddress = refundAddress;
            return this;  
        }

        public HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody build(){

            HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody order = new HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody(); 
            order.depositHotel = this.depositHotel;
            order.depositHotelAmount = this.depositHotelAmount;
            order.destinationAddress = this.destinationAddress;
            order.destinationHotel = this.destinationHotel;
            order.destinationHotelAmount = this.destinationHotelAmount;
            order.refundAddress = this.refundAddress;

            return order;

        }
    }


    private String depositHotel;
    private String destinationHotel;
    private Float depositHotelAmount;
    private Float destinationHotelAmount;
    private Address destinationAddress;
    private Address refundAddress;


    private HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody () {
        //Constructor is now private.
    }


    public String getDepositHotel() {
        return depositHotel;
    }


    public void setDepositHotel(String depositHotel) {
        this.depositHotel = depositHotel;
    }


    public String getDestinationHotel() {
        return destinationHotel;
    }


    public void setDestinationHotel(String destinationHotel) {
        this.destinationHotel = destinationHotel;
    }


    public Float getDepositHotelAmount() {
        return depositHotelAmount;
    }


    public void setDepositHotelAmount(Float depositHotelAmount) {
        this.depositHotelAmount = depositHotelAmount;
    }


    public Float getDestinationHotelAmount() {
        return destinationHotelAmount;
    }


    public void setDestinationHotelAmount(Float destinationHotelAmount) {
        this.destinationHotelAmount = destinationHotelAmount;
    }


    public Address getDestinationAddress() {
        return destinationAddress;
    }


    public void setDestinationAddress(Address destinationAddress) {
        this.destinationAddress = destinationAddress;
    }


    public Address getRefundAddress() {
        return refundAddress;
    }

    public void setRefundAddress(Address refundAddress) {
        this.refundAddress = refundAddress;
    }
}
```

and

```
public test postOrder ( HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody order) {



        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(new JSONObject(order).toString(), headers());

        ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> response = new RestTemplate()
                  .exchange(URL, 
                          HttpMethod.POST, entity,  new ParameterizedTypeReference<OrderResponse>() {});

        return response.getBody();

    }
```

But i have this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at io.bonanza.backend.service.Hotelswitch.HotelswitchHotelService.postOrder(HotelswitchHotelService.java:132)
    at io.bonanza.backend.service.Hotelswitch.HotelswitchHotelServiceTests.testPostOrder(HotelswitchHotelServiceTests.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.9.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>





        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
           <!--  <version>4.5.4</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
       </dependency>


        <!-- Firebase dependencies -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>0.26.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Add your POM please. This is normally due to not allowing Spring to manage dependencies.it manages.

Comment: Some times there are problems with the dependencies in the pom.xml file ( Maven). There could be many reasons for that: a conflict in versions, or conflict declaring the same dependency twice with different versions.

Comment: Could you post the result of mvn dependency:tree?

Comment: Which Java version are you using to run this?

Comment: For this problem, there are multi-version of [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) imported. The solution is exclude it from the dependency from which it was import, and specify the expected one. Furthermore, you can use [fastjson](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fastjson/) which was also imported in your project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you have more than one org.json:json dependency on your classpath.

Looking at it:

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` depends on

`com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path` which in turn brings

`org.json:json` which is may be newer/older than the version on which

`io.jsonwebtoken jjwt 0.9.1` is dependent on

You could try excluding this transitive dependency from spring-boot-starter-test/io.jsonwebtoken:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

OR/AND

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But it's possible that there is something within json-path which depends on something from the older json library, which is no longer in the newer version, so proceed with caution and test everything thoroughly.
There is also a chance that something else brings org.json:json.

To verify, please run `mvn dependency:tree` and search in the produced output for `org.json:json`.

Comment: Please comment if there was any problem following the answer or if didn't work. If it solved the problem accepting the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Please check this link :
[spring-boot issue 8706](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8706)

Exclusion of android-json from spring-boot-starter-test worked for me.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Adding this embedded exclusion tag worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found this on another page. I tried the checked answer here and it didn't work with mine, but when I inserted this into my pom file it worked. I'm running unit tests with mockito and one of the endpoints uses JSONObject.put and was giving me the no such method error.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>
            org.springframework.boot
        </groupId>
        <artifactId>
            spring-boot-starter-test
        </artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This worked for me BUT also I had to refresh my Maven dependencies after the change.   Thanks.

Comment: Also worked for me. Adding just org.json exclusion wasn't enough. (spring-boot 2.4.4 and Junit 5)

Answer (score 0):

Your `destinationAddress` and `refundAddress` are passed as list of address or address array in the JSON while in the `HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody` your `destinationAddress` and `refundAddress` are refered to as single Address Element. Update your pojo or JSON and try again. This might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your POJO to JSONObject using ObjectMapper or include [json dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036857/create-jsonobject-from-pojo)

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.json</groupId>
>     <artifactId>json</artifactId>
>     <version>20180130</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be the destinationAddress and refundAddress is mismatch between your JSON and POJO.
Try to change your JSON like this:

`{
    "depositHotel": "xxx",
    "destinationHotel": "aaa",
    "depositHotelAmount": "0.2",
    "destinationHotelAmount": "4",
    "destinationAddress": {
        "address": "asdf",
        "tag": ""
    },
    "refundAddress": {
        "address": "pio",
        "tag": ""
    }
}`

If you dont want to change your JSON, change your Builder POJO to use Address[] instead of Address object.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need the JSONobject

```
HttpEntity<HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody> entity = new HttpEntity<HotelswitchHotelOrderRequestBody>(order, headers());
```

if all you want to do is to convert your object to a string then use an object mapper.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car)
```