# Saving nested JSON data into a MySQL database using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, hibernate

I am strucked with this issue. I have created a POJO for nested JSON and I am getting data in `MarketPrice` object where `marketPrices` is an `ArrayList` which has two elements.

This is MarketPrice POJO class and actually I need to save it into the `MarketPrice` table. I.e, entire JSON object. But I have two entities. How can this be possible?

**MarketPrice.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MarketPrice")

public class MarketPrice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "itemId")
private Long itemId;

@Column(name = "analysisDate")
private Date analysisDate;

@Column(name = "marketName")
private String marketName;

@Column(name = "category")
private String category;

@Column(name = "marketPlace")
private String marketPlace;

@Column(name = "state")
private String state;

@Column(name = "district")
private String district;


public ArrayList<Items> marketPrices;
```

**Items.java**

```
public class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2428562977284114465L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "itemName")
    private String itemName;

    @Column(name = "unitofPrice")
    private String unitofPrice;

    @Column(name = "minimumPrice",columnDefinition = "Float(10,2)")
    private Float minimumPrice;

    @Column(name = "maximumPrice",columnDefinition = "Float(10,2)")
    private Float maximumPrice;
```

This is my nested JSON data I'm getting from at the server side in the controller:

**JSON data in `marketPrices`**

```
{
    "marketPrices": [{
        "itemName": "Mango",
        "unitofPrice": "Kg",
        "minimumPrice": "10",
        "maximumPrice": "20"
    }, {
        "itemName": "Grapes",
        "unitofPrice": "Kg",
        "minimumPrice": "30",
        "maximumPrice": "40"
    }],
    "state": "xyz",
    "district": 4,
    "marketPlace": 5001,
    "marketName": "pmc",
    "category": "Fruits"
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/saveAnalysis"} , method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public MarketPrice bulkSaveMarketAnalysis(@RequestBody 
        String marketPrices, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException, JSONException{

    MarketPrice marketPrice1 = new MarketPrice();
    System.out.println("Json Data"+marketPrices);//here am getting valid nested json from UI
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MarketPrice marketPrice = gson.fromJson(marketPrices, MarketPrice.class);//converting it into Entity type all values are present in it.
    //Am strucked after this,How to save nested json into DB.

    String marketDataResponse =  analyserService.saveListOfMarketPrice(marketPrice);
    marketPrice1.setStatusMessage("success");
    return marketPrice1;
}
```

**DAO.java**

```
public String saveListOfMarketPrice(MarketPrice marketPrice) {
    System.out.println("In Analyser DAO fro bulk saving");
    final Session session = getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    marketPrice.setAnalysisDate(new Date());
    for (Items item : marketPrice.marketPrices) {
       marketPrice.currentItem = item;
       marketPrice.setItemName(marketPrice.currentItem.getItemName());
       marketPrice.setUnitofPrice(marketPrice.currentItem.getUnitofPrice());
       marketPrice.setMinimumPrice(marketPrice.currentItem.getMinimumPrice());
       marketPrice.setMaximumPrice(marketPrice.currentItem.getMaximumPrice());
        session.save(marketPrice);
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return "success";
}
```

After making these changes to DAO it saved finally
Thank you.

Comment: as i understood, conversion from json to pojo is correct ? this analyserService is your DAO.java ? Lastly, i don't think you require to make for loop for saving each marketprice. Saving the marketPrice object will save parent object and child object both in one instance (as far i know).

Comment: but you need to create relation between MarketPlace and Items Classes like onetomany

Comment: where is your mapping between two tables i.e. one to many

Comment: I have described that in my answer

Comment: i have added mapping for two tables,please do check it.

Comment: @Hema, your `public class Items` is missing the `@Table` annotation.

Comment: @Hema, Also, remove the for loop in `saveListOfMarketPrice` method and just add `session.save(marketPrice);` after `session.beginTransaction();` and do commit and close the session.

Comment: @Aruna, All the details should be saved in MarketPrice table only,so is '@Table' annotation needed for Items class..?

Comment: @Hema, In that case, you don't need a `@ManyToOne` annotation. What is the column name to store `public ArrayList<Items> marketPrices` ?

Comment: @Hema, you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can modify your code as below to make it work as expected.

**MarketPrice.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MarketPrice")

public class MarketPrice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "itemId")
private Long itemId;

@Column(name = "analysisDate")
private Date analysisDate;

@Column(name = "marketName")
private String marketName;

@Column(name = "category")
private String category;

@Column(name = "marketPlace")
private String marketPlace;

@Column(name = "state")
private String state;

@Column(name = "district")
private String district;

 @Transient
 public Items currentItem;

@Column(name = "itemName")
public String getItemName() {
    return this.currentItem.itemName;
}

@Column(name = "unitofPrice")
public String getUnitofPrice() {
    return this.currentItem.unitofPrice;
}

@Column(name = "minimumPrice",columnDefinition = "Float(10,2)")
public Float getMinimumPrice() {
    return this.currentItem.minimumPrice;
}

@Column(name = "maximumPrice",columnDefinition = "Float(10,2)")
public Float getMaximumPrice() {
    return this.currentItem.maximumPrice;
}

@Transient
public ArrayList<Items> marketPrices;
```

**Items.java**

```
public class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2428562977284114465L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    public String itemName;

    public String unitofPrice;

    public Float minimumPrice;

    public Float maximumPrice;
```

**DAO.java**

```
public String saveListOfMarketPrice(MarketPrice marketPrice) {
        System.out.println("In Analyser DAO fro bulk saving");
        final Session session = getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        for (Items item : marketPrice.marketPrices) {
           marketPrice.currentItem = item;
           session.save(marketPrice);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: I have added previously saved DB format. and i need save in that format only.Even i don want marketPrice column also.

Comment: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started ............and all columns which are in ITEMS class are saving NULL values

Comment: I have moved the line `session.getTransaction().commit();` out of `for` loop.

Comment: itemName,unitofPrice,minimumPrice and maxPrice are saving as NULL values

Comment: Can you confirm whether the json is correctly set to the `marketPrices` object as per your comment `//converting it into Entity type all values are present in it`?

Comment: Yes all values are there

Comment: Can you able to debug the for loop after setting the currentItem?

Comment: insert into MarketPrice (analysisDate, category, district, marketName, marketPlace, state) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate generated query,here no itemName unitofPrice maxPrice and minPrice parameters only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142054/discussion-between-hema-and-aruna).

Comment: Thank you so much, You are a techie Star.. Finally the values saved into DB. with lots n lots of ur help. But left with one issue too:(

Comment: Great, have you fixed it?

Comment: Yes fixed it,Means its saving same record multiple times. May be issue in for eachloop i guess

Comment: Great, I left the office and was out after that. So can't able to help you after that and it's 11pm in Sydney now. Try some more otherwise, will look out tomorrow. The reason why it may save the same record multiple time could be because of updating the same object again and again as hibernate may have the generated Id in the memory. So you can create a new object inside the for loop by cloning the existing object and try to update it. Anyways, FYI I am not a Java developer but basically a dot net and NodeJS developer :-) just was trying to help you as you explicitly called me :-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should create one bigger entity for the whole Json ant it will have a list of you marketPrice objects @onetomany. Read about that annotation. And also parse your whole incoming object at once not only the list of marketPrices inside. You can read how to parse your whole object here: [GSON parsing without a lot of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595493/gson-parsing-without-a-lot-of-classes)

You need something like:
JsonObject rootObj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

Then you should describe that structure in an entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "your_table")
public class YourEntity{
//you should describe your parameters here too
//of the parsed json. it has other data in it not only the list of `MarketPrices`...


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "yourEntity",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MarketPrice> prices;
```

.....